# date time variable into crontab -e url

Tags: ssh, cron, centos

i try to work with crontab -e into ssh at centos  6
i can't work with variable into crontab -e
i try many times to get it to work but i failed to run with it

```
MYDATE=`date`


*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --head -sf http://localhost/php.php?date=$MYDATE -o /dev/null || /restart.sh
```

i can't work with variable into crontab -e
i try many times to get it to work but i failed to run with it

i need date into url to make refresh url every time because i use high cache i need to 
test url every time with new one

there any way to run it every minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
* * * * * SUFFIX=`date +\%M`; cp /home/temp.php /home/temp3_${SUFFIX}.php >/dev/null
```